# Want to extract decimal number from a page with xpath, selenium wedriver in python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have a page having item price as shown in attached image. i want to extract this price as 64.99. I want to ask what would be the xpath to get this number as Im using selenium webdriver to find this price[image: HTML of the page on which im trying to get the price with selenium webdriver]

I have tried a lot of permutations of xpaths but the problem is that this page have a lot such products so its being difficult to find unique xpath of that price. e.g -

//li[@class = 'price-current'] (gives 13 result on the page)

//*[@id = 'landingpage-price' and @class = 'price-current']  (give no result)

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: please post the url of this page in your question, So, that it will helps others to give you answer and also post your tried code!

Comment: where is your sample code ?

Comment: Here is what im trying so far -
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//li[@class = 'price-current'])[2]")
print (elem.text)

this print $64.99 which is correct. what im asking the unique xpath to point on this number

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mentioned there are lot of such products, then the problem you are asking is wrong. You need to find out how to get to the product that you are interested in and then find its price. You are trying to find the price directly.

Now the issue in below xpath

```
//*[@id = 'landingpage-price' and @class = 'price-current'] (give no result)
```

is that, you are trying to search inside `landingpage-price` and specifying the `class` condition also on the container element. First I would suggest do this using css, but I will show both xpath and css as well.

**XPath**

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id = 'landingpage-price']//li[@class = 'price-current']")
print (elem.text.replace("$",""))
```

**CSS**

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#landingpage-price  .price-current")
print (elem.text.replace("$",""))
```

You xpath would break if developers adds more classes to the price. So using a css is better and it does work also. As you can see in below image it uniquely identified the element

[image: Working CSS]

Comment: Thank you very much Tarun. Very detailed and helpful answer from which I learned some new things. Stay blessed!